# How can I write an interface using fastapi to query the contents of a table that currently exists in an Oracle database?

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, fastapi

Currently my Oracle database already exists in two tables: table1 and table2, I want to write an interface to achieve the input parameters cn, the output of the corresponding results.

The code is :

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, Session
import cx_Oracle

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String

cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client(lib_dir=r"E:\instantclient-basic-windows.x64-12.1.0.2.0\instantclient_12_1")

my_database_connection = "oracle+cx_oracle://super:admin@192.168.91.47:1521/db"

engine = create_engine(my_database_connection)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = "table1"
    CN = Column(String(length=256))
    NAME = Column(String(length=40))
    EMAIL = Column(String(length=20))

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
# Base.metadata.
app = FastAPI()

def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

@app.get("/table_api/")
def read_users(db:Session = Depends(get_db)):
    cninformation = db.query(table1).all()
    return cninformation
```

Since table1 already exists, the above code Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) is wrong because this line of code creates the table1 table, if I want to connect to a table that already exists, the Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine) line should be replaced with what code?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean, if you don't need to create the table, don't create the table? Just leave the `create_all` line out?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change the `create_all` line.  `MetaData.create_all`, takes a parameter, [checkfirst](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData.create_all.params.checkfirst) which checks whether a table exists before trying to create it. The default value of `checkfirst` is `True`, so if the table already exists it will be ignored.

If you prefer a more explicit approach, you can look at the options described in [Mapping Declaratively with Reflected Tables](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/declarative_tables.html#mapping-declaratively-with-reflected-tables), or use an [imperative mapping](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/mapping_styles.html#imperative-mapping) with a [reflected](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/reflection.html#reflecting-database-objects)  table. Or you can mix and match to suit your particular requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one brief snippet (without SQLAlchemy):

```
# test.py

from fastapi import FastAPI

import getpass
import os

import oracledb

un = os.environ.get('PYTHON_USERNAME')
cs = os.environ.get('PYTHON_CONNECTSTRING')
pw = getpass.getpass(f'Enter password for {un}@{cs}: ')


pool = oracledb.create_pool(user=un, password=pw, dsn=cs, min=1, max=4)

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}

@app.get("/items/")
def getitems(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 10):

    with pool.acquire() as connection:
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            sql = """select json_object(first_name)
                     from employees
                     offset :offset rows fetch next :maxnumrows rows only"""
            cursor.execute(sql, [skip, limit])
            r = cursor.fetchall()
            #print(r)
            return r
```

For readers starting with FastAPI:

```
python3 -m pip install "fastapi[all]" oracledb
uvicorn test:app --reload
```

and then load this in a browser window:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/items/?skip=0&limit=2
```